# QMatrix4x4 Model View Projection OpenGL Can't Get Scene to Render

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Given this vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 vertex;
uniform mat4 mvp;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
}
```

And this fragment shader:

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Which is able to render the data below, when the `mvp` matrix is the identity or if the model matrix is a scale, rotate, or tranlate transform:

```
GLfloat values[] = {
    -1.0, -1.0, +0.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, +0.0,
    +0.0, +1.0, +0.0,
};
```

Why does the following usage of Qt's `QMatrix4x4::lookAt` and `QMatrix4x4::perspective` cause the scene to be rendered as if no object is there?

```
QMatrix4x4 model;
QMatrix4x4 view;
view.lookAt(
  QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 10.0), // Eye
  QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), // Focal Point
  QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); // Up vector
QMatrix4x4 proj;
// Window size is fixed at 800.0 by 600.0
proj.perspective(45.0, 800.0 / 600.0, 1.0, 100.0);
QMatrix4x4 mvp = (model * view * proj);
```

What I am looking for is not only how to fix the code but by which means I can attempt to debug these things in the future.

---

Just on a hunch I changed mvp to p * v * m and it fixed the issue. Why is it mvp if you have to do the multiplication in the opposite order? I know matrix multiplication is not transitive. That is if A and B are matrices, A * B != B * A if A and B are not I.

Comment: You're right that the order has to be `p * v * m`, but that comes down to the way matrix memory is laid out in Qt (and OpenGL frameworks in general). If you were to write these matrices out on paper and do the math yourself, you would find that `m * v * p` was the correct order since you work from left-to-right. Likewise, if you did this in a framework that uses row-major matrices (e.g. D3DX) it would also be `m * v * p`. But if you transpose all of those matrices (which is effectively what column-major matrices do), you need to reverse the order of operations to get the same result.

Comment: @Coleman column major order doesn't transpose anything, it's just a way to store the information. Everything depends on how is implemented multiplication, you can do it as rows by columns or columns by rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called MVP because... somebody named it that way. ;)

It makes some sense, though. It basically lists the transformations in the order they are applied. You first apply the Model matrix to your vertices, then the View matrix to the result of that, then the projection matrix to the result of both.

Or mathematically, for an input vertex `vObj`, you could write:

```
vWorld = M * vObj
vEye = V * vWorld
vClip = P * vEye
```

If you substitute the equations, you get:

```
vClip = P * vEye = P * (V * vWorld) = P * (V * (M * vObj))
```

Matrix multiplications are associative, so this can be rewritten as:

```
P * (V * (M * vObj)) = (P * V * M) * vObj
```

Therefore, the combined matrix is calculated as `P * V * M`.

Answer (score 1):

Reto Koradi is right. And it's not because of memory layout or something, it's because OpenGL uses column vectors - matrix with four rows and one column or 4x1 matrix. Transformations are Matrix4x4 * Vector to meet criteria for matrix multiplications (result is column vector again).

Another approach is to define vector as row (1x4 matrix) and then all transformations are `vWorld = vObj * M` etc to meet criteria for matrix multiplication resulting in row vector. Out of sudden, last row is rewritten as `vClip = vObj * M * V * P`.

Matrix multiplication is always the same, you should not need to care how matrices are stored in the memory (well, unless it's linear array and you need to address element at row/column), but transform matrices are different depending on definition of vector.

<del>In OpenGL always compose transforms from right to left. Remember that left-most matrix is applied last.</del>

For some reason (history?), vectors are usually considered column vectors and transform matrices are applied from right to left, but as noted in the comment below, it's possible to use both approaches in GL Shading Language (GLSL).

Comment: `"it's because OpenGL uses column vectors"` It does not. Vectors can work as both rows and columns. For example, `vector * transpose(mvp)` will work just fine, and `vector` will act as a row vector.

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the dimensionality of matrices and mathematical notation. The dimensions of a matrix are defined as rows x columns. So a 1x3 matrix is M = [a b c]. Then a 4x4 matrix is as expected.

Multiplying two matrices of dimension AxB and CxD can only be done if B=C (row into column and sum the result).

A list of N vertices with XYZW coordinates can be defined as a matrix Nx4 or 4xN in size, but only 4xN works with the definition of the multiplication operator if the block of vertices come after the matrix:

V' (4xN) = M (4x4) x V (4xN)

So vertices are considered as column vectors to make this notation work.